# Diagram Drawing Tool in Editor

Tags: feature-request

It would be very nice if this editor had a diagram drawer, don't yall think?

Like with easy drag-and-drop tools to place boxes and vectors for free-body diagrams, springs, circuit components, etc. etc.

Comment: If you're offering to write the code for it (but probably not even then)... Otherwise, I'm pretty sure it's a non-starter since  it would be a relatively big project with a relatively small impact (in terms of the entire SE network).

Comment: If you can get SE on board, I will write the program for a large fee

Comment: There have been questions before on this subject, I think most people use different tools but Google draw did appear as one viable tool.

Comment: For those who draw diagrams the hard... I mean **fun**... way, you can build your diagrams in tikz with latex and then convert to a png and upload that. See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3190/graphs-in-questions-tikz for example, although I feel like I found a latex package that allowed using ImageMagick to directly compile to png in combination with `standalone`. But I can't seem to find it now.

Comment: I think the impact would be quite large, considering how it would raise the quality of questions and responses, and its wide applicability. I'm sure the math and chem guys would love one, and it could be made in such a way that any website can implement it (although I guess this means it makes more sense for someone to develop this independently, and then for SE to simply implement it). It could start very basic and then developers add specific tools over time. I'll take a crack at getting it started in a couple weeks.

Comment: **_Totally agreed!_**

Comment: Exact duplicate of John Rennie's link. Have you got some pre-existing software in mind, or were you hoping SE would build one just for this site?